# How to check an IP Address Reachable or not

Tags: android

In my application I have checked whether ineternet connection is there using the below code

```
   private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {    
             ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
             NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();  
             return activeNetworkInfo != null; }
```

Now the problem is that how can i check whether conncetion to one remote computer Ip is exist or not...I need to connect to an external IP webservice.....Need to check connetion to that .Suppose the link is like as given below

http://192.168.1.158/VisionEPODWebservice/Manifest.asmx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
InetAddress.getByName(ip).isReachable(timeout);
```

see documentation of [InetAddress](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html)

Comment: InetAddress.getByName(ip).isReachable(timeout); Found error at the same line.."java.lang.NullPointerException". Can you suggest me what is the reason behind that

Comment: Referring the documentation: IOException -> network error; IllegalArgumentException -> negative timeout (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress#isReachable(int))